# How do I get and display JSON with HTTParty?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json

I'm new to Ruby on Rails and programming in general. So far I've successfully used my console to return JSON data from an API but I can't seem to make it work on my local server.

In the console I entered:

```
httparty "http://rubygems.org/api/v1/versions/httparty.json"
```

and it returned the JSON after I managed to install/configure everything.

So then in the console I wrote:

```
rails new Catalog
rails generate controller new index
```

I followed the tutorial to get `<h1>Hello, Rails!</h1>` to display on my page when I go to:

```
http://localhost:3000/
```

Now I am trying to get the JSON data returned and display on that same page where it says "Hello, Rails".

In index.html.erb I have:

```
<h1>Hello, Rails</h1>
<%= @result %>
```

In home_controller.rb I have:

```
class HomeController < ApplicationController
  def get_catalog
  include HTTParty
  @result = HTTParty.get("http://rubygems.org/api/v1/versions/httparty.json")
  end
end
```

In routes.rb I have:

```
Catalog::Application.routes.draw do
  get "home/index"
  root :to => 'home#index'
end
```

Nothing appears under "Hello, Rails" when I go to the page.

I'm still trying to wrap my head around how all of this stuff interacts with each other. Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong here perhaps?

--- Update
I'm trying to output just the product names into li elements. My files now are:

**index.html.erb:**

```
<ul>
  <% @http_party_json.each do |event| %>
      <% event.each do |e| %>
          <li><%=h e['Products']['Name'] %></li>
      <% end %>
  <% end %>
</ul>
```

**controller:**

```
class HomeController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @response =     HTTParty.get("myURL")
    @http_party_json = JSON.parse(@response.body)
  end
end
```

The error I am getting is:

```
undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass
Extracted source (around line #5):

2: <ul>
3:   <% @http_party_json.each do |event| %>
4:       <% event.each do |e| %>
5:           <li><%=h e['Products']['Name'] %></li>
6:       <% end %>
7:   <% end %>
8: </ul>
```

When I take off the ['Name'] I get JSON starting with:

```
[{"Name"=>"3x4 Vinyl Magnet", "Description"=>"Made of durable high-gloss vinyl.  Measures 3x4 inches and has rounded corners. Waterproof and scratch resistant."
```

Why can't I target ['Name'] to get just the product names?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`HTTParty.get` returns an object of the type `HTTParty::Response`, which is documented in [HTTParty](https://github.com/jnunemaker/httparty) (Check out the examples.)

There is a nice helper method on `HTTParty::Response` called `#parsed_response. This returns the JSON string parsed into a Hash or Array:

```
HTTParty.get("URL").parsed_response
```

Alternatively, in order to get the body of this message, you can call `@result.body`. This returns a string, which you can safely output to your page as you did. However, I'm guessing you want to do more with it than just output it to a page.

In order to parse this into a [hash](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/ruby/ruby_hashes.htm)/Array that you can use/manipulate/return as true JSON you would do something like:

```
http_party_json = JSON.parse(@response.body)
```

So with this, you could do something like the following in your controller if you wanted to be able to return JSON:

```
@response = HTTParty.get("http://rubygems.org/api/v1/versions/httparty.json").parsed_response
respond_to do |format|
   format.json { render :json => JSON.parse(@result) }
   format.html { render "index.html.erb" }
end
```

**Updated answer based on your updated information:**

It appears as though `e['Products']` returns an array (notice the square brackets on the outside.) So, if you are only expecting one you could do:

```
e['Products'][0]['Name']
```

If it might return multiple products, you might, instead, need to account for the possibility of many products and use an `each` block:

```
e['Products'].each do |product|
    #do something with product['Name']
end
```

It just depends on your needs for the app.

Comment: Hey Joe, I made an edit to my post, hoping you could take a quick look. Thanks if you can!

Comment: It appears as though `e['Products']` returns an array (notice the square brackets on the outside.) So, if you are only expecting one you could do `e['Products'][0]['Name']`. If it might return multiple products, you might, instead, need to account for the possibility of many products and use an `e['Products'].each do |product|; product['Name']`. It just depends on your needs for the app.

Answer (score 6):

HTTParty parses XML/JSON responses for you. Simply use `parsed_response` to get it:

```
@response = HTTParty.get("URL").parsed_response
```